# Spark Date column initializers for "withColumn"?

Tags: apache-spark

Scala 2.11 here. I have the following DB table:

```
[input]
===
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
rank INT NOT NULL
```

That I read with the following Spark code:

```
val inputDf = sqlContext().read
    .format("blah whatever")
    .option("url", "jdbc://blah://whatever")
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM input WHERE id < 500")
    .load()
```

However I would like my `inputDf` to contain a new column that doesn't exist in the database, `lastRanOn`, which would be a Java `Date` with a value of the current time (so `new Date()`). The closest I could come up with was:

```
inputDf.withColumn("lastRanOn", new Date())
```

However that gives me compiler errors:

> "Type mismatch, expected: Column, actual: Date"

**Any ideas how I can accomplish this?**

Comment: You can transform a value into a column using the `lit()` function.  However, it does not support all types.  You will have to use java.sql types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument has to be a `Column`. You can use `current_date`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_date

inputDf.withColumn("lastRanOn", current_date)
```